# beginner - how to test a widget?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-widget

I downloaded the 'ExampleAppWidget' (by Android Official documentation).
I opened it with Eclipse. I've no compiling errors.
I'm trying to test it pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> key (as with a classic application that is not a widget), but I think that this is not the right way, as a matter of fact Android return me a null pointer exception at runtime.
The question is: HOW TO TEST A WIDGET DEVELOPED WITH ECLIPSE, ON ANDROID?

Thanks very much indeed in advance!
Geltry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the widget icon didn't compare in the widget list. In the AndroidManifest, add the  tag, as (f.i.):

Answer (score 0):

Just long press on the home screen and add the widget to test it?